# MemoryError using Android Publisher upload.py script

Tags: android, python, google-play, google-play-services

I have to upload 8 files using Android Publisher `upload.py` script (4 - *.apk and 4 - *.obb), each APK is about 11MB and each OBB is about 400MB.

The procedure starts OK the first APK is beeing uploaded but when the script is trying to upload the first OBB I am getting `MemoryError`

```
Start uploading a:\TemporaryUploadFolder\NAME.apk
Version code 510 has been uploaded
Start uploading         
a:\TemporaryUploadFolder\NAME.obb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File     
"C:\agent\src\AutoQueueingModule2\
BuildServer.Agent\Utility\GoogleUploader\upload.py", line 107, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File 
"C:\agent\src\AutoQueueingModule2\
BuildServer.Agent\Utility\GoogleUploader\upload.py", line 86, in main
obb_response = 
service.edits().expansionfiles().
upload(apkVersionCode=apk_response['versionCode'], expansionFileType='main', 
editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name, media_body=obb_file).execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 135, in 
positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 827, in 
execute
method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 154, in 
_retry_request
resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 631, in 
new_request
redirections, connection_type)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1609, in 
request
(response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, 
method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1351, in 
_request
(response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, 
headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1273, in 
_conn_request
conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1057, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1097, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 895, in _send_output
msg += message_body
MemoryError
```

I know that there is a [limitation of files size to 2GB](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/expansionfiles/upload), but any file of these has more then 500MB. I also would like to mention that this script worked before and suddenly stopped.

Comment: Did you check this [github forum](https://gist.github.com/marta-rodriguez/20b8684e76fb1262576e)? It seems related as you're both using python for the upload.

Comment: This script use the same method to upload files: https://gist.github.com/mix3d/665f4ab329b4482297a2f425ebba402c#file-basic_upload_apks_service_account-py-L49 so it is displaying the same error when using obb file, the apk file is uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Python 64bit this problem now longer accurs.